# childclass should use parent's ToString()

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have a base class `Sport` defined as:

```
public class Sport
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}

   public Sport() {}

   public override string ToString()
   {
     string objectState = string.Format("[Id: {0}; Name: {1};]", Id, Name);
     return objectState;
   }
}
```

and I have second class which inherits the `Sport` class:

```
public class Basketball : Sport
{
   public string PointTerm {get; set;}
   public Basketball() {}      

   //overriding ToString()??
}
```

How do I override `ToString` from my base Sport class with an additional property `PointTerm`?

Comment: You'll do it the same way you did in the `Sport` class...

Comment: @Servy, so basically I should override ToString in every class where I want to use ?

Comment: If you want the string representation of that object to be different then it's parent, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add a new override in your `Basketball` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("[Id: {0}; Name: {1}; PointTerm: {2};]",
                         Id, Name, PointTerm);
}
```

**Edit:**

You could do something like this if you want to keep in sync with the base class's implementation, **but the simpler approach above is probably better in most circumstances**:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    char[] openingBracket = new char[] { '[' };
    char[] closingBracket = new char[] { ']' };     

    string trimmedBaseString = (base.ToString() ?? string.Empty)
                               .TrimStart(openingBracket).TrimEnd(closingBracket);
    return string.Format("[{0} PointTerm: {1};]", trimmedBaseString, PointTerm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good solution in your case (or in *any* case), but of course it's possible to find all properties defined on your type (whether it be `Sport`, `Basketball` or some other derived type) using **reflection**.

Maybe if you write like this inside your `Sport` class:

```
public sealed override string ToString()
{
    var allStrings = GetType().GetProperties()
        .Select(p => p.Name + ": " + p.GetValue(this, null));
    return "[" + string.Join("; ", allStrings) + ";]";
}
```

Then `Sport` and all types deriving from it will have `ToString` defined the same way, and it will use reflection to find all (public) properties.